# What is a TROC Filesystem, and how do I mount it?

Tags: firmware, file-format

I decompiled a piece of firmware using `binwalk` and found an entry for a `TROC Filesystem`:

```
 DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1064340       0x103D94        Copyright string: "Copyright 2006 Techsonic Industries, Inc. - All Rights Reserved"
 1084664       0x108CF8        Copyright string: "Copyright 2007 Techsonic Industries, Inc. - All Rights Reserved"
 1211854       0x127DCE        TROC filesystem, 256 file entries
 1671429       0x198105        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecosonda"
 1735998       0x1A7D3E        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecoscandaglio"
```

While I have seen a number of blogs that got a similar output, none of them seem to actually identify what `TROC` stands for, or how to mount it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the firmware from and what device is it for?

Comment: You should probably have included some more information that you know already about the firmware, but a cursory research using web searches seems to suggest some relation to Linksys firmwares in particular. Going by [this](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/5313/) it doesn't look exactly difficult to interpret. But what TROC stands for other than *The Rest of Canada* I could not find.